# How to pass all columns except one as argument to setkey()?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to pass column names to `setkey()` except one or two . I can easily do it like below:

```
setkey(df, column1, column2, column3, column6, ..., columnN, physical = TRUE)
```

(please note that `column4` and `column5` are skipped).

But it requires me to list all column names except some particular columns. I can get list of columns with `colnames(df)`, but I am not sure how to (1) pass it to `setkey()` and (2) exclude some columns from that list?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks - this is almost what I need. How should I define columns for exclusion by their names (`column4` and `column5`)? And, could you please post it as the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try using `setkeyv` which can accept a character vector of column names and then use a simple indexing.

For example, ignoring columns by **position**

```
setkeyv(df, names(df)[-(4:5)])
```

Or ignoring columns by **vector of column names** (combined with `setdiff`)

```
ignore <- c("column4", "column5")
setkeyv(df, setdiff(names(df), ignore))
```