# data.table - group by all except one column

Tags: r, data.table

Can I group by all columns except one using `data.table`? I have a lot of columns, so I'd rather avoid writing out all the `colnames`.

The reason being I'd like to collapse duplicates in a table, where I know one column has no relevance.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- structure(list(N = c(1, 2, 2), val = c(50, 60, 60), collapse = c("A", 
"B", "C")), .Names = c("N", "val", "collapse"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

> DT
   N val collapse
1: 1  50        A
2: 2  60        B
3: 2  60        C
```

That is, given `DT`, is there something like like `DT[, print(.SD), by = !collapse]` which gives:

```
> DT[, print(.SD), .(N, val)]
   collapse
1:        A
   collapse
1:        B
2:        C
```

without actually having to specify `.(N, val)`? I realise I can do this by copy and pasting the column names, but I thought there might be some elegant way to do this too.

Comment: I think this is almost a dupe of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368785/how-to-pass-all-columns-except-one-as-argument-to-setkey

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To group by all columns except one, you can use:

```
by = setdiff(names(DT), "collapse")
```

*Explanation*: `setdiff` takes the general form of `setdiff(x, y)` which returns all values of `x` that are not in `y`. In this case it means that all columnnames are returned except the `collapse`-column.

---

Two alternatives:

```
# with '%in%'
names(dt1)[!names(dt1) %in% 'colB']

# with 'is.element'
names(dt1)[!is.element(names(dt1), 'colB')]
```