# R, data.table: Grouping by multiple columns except one

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame with 60 columns
Column 53 is causing it to duplicate as it has multiple numbers
I wish to take the max number of column 53 and group by everything else
My code is below

```
DT[,max(fee),by = DT[,-53]]
```

I get the following error

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(DT, , max(fee), by = DT[,  : 
unused argument (by = OPMS.shps[, -53])
```

I have also tried the suggestions outlined by [data.table - group by all except one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440399/data-table-group-by-all-except-one-column) but that throws the same error

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: @Jaap It is already mentioned in the OP's post.

Comment: @akrun why did you then post a same answer?

Comment: @Jaap I didn't see the link then.  Now that you posted a duplicate, I checked it.

Comment: Is DT really a Data Table ? check with `str(DT)` and maybe add a `dput(head(DT))` to your question to confirm.

Comment: Convert your dataframe to a datatable with `setDT()`. After doing that, do you still run into this error?

Comment: @Arun I kind of disagree with the duplicate close (voted for Typo, and now I even ask myself it is really).  The main problem being a data.table access on a data.frame...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to convert the `data.frame` to `data.table` before doing the `data.table` approaches.  i.e. `setDT(DT)`.

```
setDT(DT)[, max(fee), by=setdiff(names(DT), 'fee')]
```

#### data

```
 DT <- data.frame(col1= c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
           col2= rep(1:2, each=2), fee= c(1,5,3,2))
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, thanks to you and to Tensibai and Jaap, this resolved the issue. I had two data tables and used rbind to combine them and this created a data frame DT. The command throws the error until i switch it to a data table...I didn't realize rbind changes the data structure. Thanks again