# How to 'unlist' a column in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

in my table, some cells are vectors instead of single value, i.e. the column is a list instead of vector:

```
dt1 <- data.table(
  colA=   c('A1','A2','A3'), 
  colB=list('B1',c('B2a','B2b'),'B3'),
  colC=   c('C1','C2','C3'), 
  colD=   c('D1','D2','D3')
)

dt1
#   colA    colB colC colD
#1:   A1      B1   C1   D1
#2:   A2 B2a,B2b   C2   D2
#3:   A3      B3   C3   D3
```

I need to reshape it to a long format unlisting that column `colB`. So far I do it like this:

```
dt1[,.(colB=unlist(colB)),by=.(colA,colC,colD)]
#   colA colC colD colB
#1:   A1   C1   D1   B1
#2:   A2   C2   D2  B2a
#3:   A2   C2   D2  B2b
#4:   A3   C3   D3   B3
```

it does the job but I don't like that I have to indicate all other column names explicitly in `by=`. Is there better way to do this?
(I'm sure it's already answered elsewhere but I couldn't find it so far)

P.S. ideally I would like to manage without any external packages

Comment: What about `dt1[, .(colB = unlist(colB)), by = setdiff(names(dt1), 'colB')]`?

Comment: oh, I forgot that I can just put a character vector to `by=`! Could you please paste it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Do you know why in case of `setdiff()` it does not require to be wrapped in `eval()`? When I use any custom function, even completely identical (like aliased `mydiff <- setdiff;`, this raises an error: `dt1[, .(colB = unlist(colB)), by = mydiff(names(dt1), 'colB')]`

Comment: Re your comment, the error explains. Wrap in `c()` and that code works fine. I've run into that error a few times, too. Presumably the added an exception for `setdiff` since it comes up often.

Comment: Linking this: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2146

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Promoting my comment to an answer. Using:

```
dt1[,.(colB = unlist(colB)), by = setdiff(names(dt1), 'colB')]
```

gives:

> ```
>    colA colC colD colB
> 1:   A1   C1   D1   B1
> 2:   A2   C2   D2  B2a
> 3:   A2   C2   D2  B2b
> 4:   A3   C3   D3   B3
> ```

Or as an alternative (a slight variation of @Frank's proposal):

```
dt1[rep(dt1[,.I], lengths(colB))][, colB := unlist(dt1$colB)][]
```

Comment: Long time no see. I have a favor. Would you be able to explain how that setdiff part works? I get confused. I can see the logic of Frank's idea in his comment below. But, I am struggling to see yours.

Comment: @jazzurro Indeed long time no see! `setdiff` takes the general form `setdiff(x, y)` which returns all values of `x` that are not in `y`. In this case it means that all columnnames are returned except `colB`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32440436/2204410) I posted a while ago.

Comment: Hey I was thinking about this while I was at work today. So, essentially, you are grouping the data with all column names but colB, right?

Comment: Got it. I initially got confused to see setdiff in by. Now it is all clear. Thanks for your help. Hope to see you around in the chat room.

Comment: EDIT: I figured out my mistake. I'll share if anyone else runs into the "unused arguement" error:
First - I had to install and load "data.table" library....
Second - I had to convert my data.frame to a data.table by using dt1 = setDT(dataframeobject)

Answer (score 13):

I think @Jaap's is easiest, but here's another alternative to chew over:

```
#create ID column
dt1[ , ID := .I]

#unnest colB, keep ID column
dt_unnest = dt1[ , .(ID = rep(ID, lengths(colB)),
                     colB = unlist(colB))]
#merge
dt_unnest = dt_unnest[dt1[ , !'colB'], on = 'ID']
#    ID colB colA colC colD
# 1:  1   B1   A1   C1   D1
# 2:  2  B2a   A2   C2   D2
# 3:  2  B2b   A2   C2   D2
# 4:  3   B3   A3   C3   D3
```

Comment: yeah this looks less simple... But it has the advantage that it works correctly when there are other listed columns in the table. Thank you for the alternative!

Comment: @VasilyA only if the `lengths` of all `list` columns are identical... otherwise there'll need to be some sort of cross-join done

Comment: Alternately, `dt1[rep(1:.N, lengths(colB))][, colB := unlist(dt1$colB)][]`. I'd prefer this over by-group stuff (appearing in Jaap's and yours), since I expect that to slow things down.

Comment: awesome, this looks the most logical!

Comment: Following up @Frank's answer that maybe in the first step you want to exclude `colB` from the `dt1[rep(...)]` part if memory is an issue -- the `list` column can have arbitrary size and `rep`ing it could have a huge memory footprint. So something like `colB_flat = unlist(dt1$colB); dt1[rep(1:.N, lengths(colB)), !'colB']; dt1[ , colB := colB_flat]` will be more memory-efficient

Comment: Yeah, I should have had a selecting-cols step there. Fyi, we were talking about this in chat today: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44073358#44073358

Comment: @Frank thanks... in my head I remember I pictured a `CJ` approach working but it's not clicking now, could be wrong

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the game, but I was looking for a solution that accepts multiple column names. Adapted from MichaelChirico's answer with some additional safeguards and cleanups, this is what I came up with:

```r
funwrap <- function(dt, cols) {
  un <- dt[, cols, with = FALSE][, .ID := .I]
  un <- un[,
    append(
      list(.ID = rep(.ID, lengths(get(cols[[1]])))),
      stats::setNames(lapply(cols, function(vv) unlist(get(vv))), cols)
    )]
  
  # safeguard against empty values
  if (!all(cols %in% names(un))) un[, c(cols) := NA]
  
  rr <- un[dt[, !cols, with = FALSE][, .ID := .I], on = ".ID"][, .ID := NULL]
  setcolorder(rr, names(dt))
  rr[]
}

library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(
  colA =   c('A1','A2','A3'), 
  colB =list('B1',c('B2a','B2b'),'B3'),
  colC =   c('C1','C2','C3'), 
  colD =   c('D1','D2','D3')
)
r1 <- funwrap(dt1, "colB")
r1
#>    colA colB colC colD
#> 1:   A1   B1   C1   D1
#> 2:   A2  B2a   C2   D2
#> 3:   A2  B2b   C2   D2
#> 4:   A3   B3   C3   D3
str(r1)
#> Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ colA: chr  "A1" "A2" "A2" "A3"
#>  $ colB: chr  "B1" "B2a" "B2b" "B3"
#>  $ colC: chr  "C1" "C2" "C2" "C3"
#>  $ colD: chr  "D1" "D2" "D2" "D3"
#>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>

# allows multiple colums to unwrap at the same time
dt2 <- data.table(
  colA =   c('A1','A2','A3'), 
  colB =list('B1',c('B2a','B2b'),'B3'),
  colC =list('C1',c('C2a', 'C2b'),'C3'), 
  colD =   c('D1','D2','D3')
)
r2 <- funwrap(dt2, c("colB", "colC"))
r2
#>    colA colB colC colD
#> 1:   A1   B1   C1   D1
#> 2:   A2  B2a  C2a   D2
#> 3:   A2  B2b  C2b   D2
#> 4:   A3   B3   C3   D3
str(r2)
#> Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ colA: chr  "A1" "A2" "A2" "A3"
#>  $ colB: chr  "B1" "B2a" "B2b" "B3"
#>  $ colC: chr  "C1" "C2a" "C2b" "C3"
#>  $ colD: chr  "D1" "D2" "D2" "D3"
#>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>

# allows empty elements
dt3 <- data.table(
  colA =   c('A1','A2','A3'), 
  colB =list(NULL, c('B2a','B2b'), NULL),
  colC =   c('C1','C2','C3'), 
  colD =   c('D1','D2','D3')
)
r3 <- funwrap(dt3, "colB")
r3
#>    colA colB colC colD
#> 1:   A1 <NA>   C1   D1
#> 2:   A2  B2a   C2   D2
#> 3:   A2  B2b   C2   D2
#> 4:   A3 <NA>   C3   D3
str(r3)
#> Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ colA: chr  "A1" "A2" "A2" "A3"
#>  $ colB: chr  NA "B2a" "B2b" NA
#>  $ colC: chr  "C1" "C2" "C2" "C3"
#>  $ colD: chr  "D1" "D2" "D2" "D3"
#>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>

# allows fully empty lists
dt4 <- data.table(
  colA =   c('A1','A2','A3'), 
  colB =list(NULL, NULL, NULL),
  colC =   c('C1','C2','C3'), 
  colD =   c('D1','D2','D3')
)
r4 <- funwrap(dt4, "colB")
r4
#>    colA colB colC colD
#> 1:   A1   NA   C1   D1
#> 2:   A2   NA   C2   D2
#> 3:   A3   NA   C3   D3
str(r4)
#> Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ colA: chr  "A1" "A2" "A3"
#>  $ colB: logi  NA NA NA
#>  $ colC: chr  "C1" "C2" "C3"
#>  $ colD: chr  "D1" "D2" "D3"
#>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Wonderful, what I was looking for, thanks! As I had `POSIXct` inside a `list` as a column, R transforms it into `num` during `unlist`. To avoid it, I changed the lapply function into `function(vv) do.call("c", get(vv))`