# extract regex from a column and replace

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I am hoping to read a file and process it in R. It follows this format:

```
tibble(row=8,name="Shawn",state="Arizona", age=45,
comments="father=Alex;NSM;GNO;One:0.9995,0.13|Two:0.9991,0.55|Three:0.9996,0.33|Four:0.9986,0.22|Five:0.9987,0.22")
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 1 x 5
>         row name  state     age comment                                                                          
>       <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>                                                                             
>     1     8 Shawn Arizona    45 father=Alex;NSM;GNO;One:0.9995,0.13|Two:0.9991,0.55|Three:0.9996,0.33|Four:0.9986…
> ```

I would like to replace the last column with

```
comment
One:0.9995|Two:0.9991|Three:0.9996|Four:0.9986|Five:0.9987
```

and then subtract the floating number from 1:

```
comment
One:0.0005|Two:0.0009|Three:0.0004|Four:0.0014|Five:0.0013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve this using `tidyverse`. We first remove the characters till the last semi-colon and numbers followed by a comma using `gsub`. We split rows on `"|"` into separate rows and split them on `":"` in different columns and then subtract the value from 1.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(comments = gsub(".*;|,\\d\\.\\d+", "", comments)) %>%
  separate_rows(comments, sep = "\\|") %>%
  separate(comments, into = c('num', 'value'), sep = ":", convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(value = 1 - value)

# A tibble: 5 x 6
#    row name  state     age num      value
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#1     8 Shawn Arizona    45 One   0.000500
#2     8 Shawn Arizona    45 Two   0.0009  
#3     8 Shawn Arizona    45 Three 0.000400
#4     8 Shawn Arizona    45 Four  0.00140 
#5     8 Shawn Arizona    45 Five  0.00130
```

If needed as summarised value again, we can add to the chain

```
%>% group_by(row, name, state, age) %>%
    summarise(comments = paste(num, round(value, 5), collapse = "|", sep = ":"))

#   row name  state     age comments                                                  
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>                                                     
#1     8 Shawn Arizona    45 One:0.0005|Two:0.0009|Three:0.0004|Four:0.0014|Five:0.0013
```

Answer (score 2):

This function is not particularly performant or elegant, but it will give you exactly the output you asked for. It is not vectorized, but you could use `sapply` to fix that.

```r
sample <- "father=Alex;NSM;GNO;One:0.9995,0.13|Two:0.9991,0.55|Three:0.9996,0.33|Four:0.9986,0.22|Five:0.9987,0.22"

extract_numbers <- function(x) {
  x <- sub(".*;", "", x)
  x <- gsub(",([0-9.]*)|", "", x)
  x <- strsplit(x, "|", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
  do.call(
    "paste", 
    c(
      lapply(
        strsplit(x, ":"), 
        function(y) paste(y[1], sprintf("%6.4f", 1 - as.numeric(y[2])), sep = ":")
      ),
      sep = "|"
    )
  )
}

extract_numbers(sample)
# [1] "One:0.0005|Two:0.0009|Three:0.0004|Four:0.0014|Five:0.0013"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strsplit` and `tstrsplit` from `data.table` like so (call your table `DT`):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

DT = DT[ , c(.SD, tstrsplit(comments, ';', fixed = TRUE))]
DT = DT[ , strsplit(V9, '|', fixed = TRUE), by = row]
DT[ , c('key', 'val1', 'val2') := tstrsplit(V1, '[:,]', type.convert = TRUE)]
DT[ , val1 := 1-val1][]
#      row                V1    key   val1  val2
# 1:     8   One:0.9995,0.13    One 0.0005  0.13
# 2:     8   Two:0.9991,0.55    Two 0.0009  0.55
# 3:     8 Three:0.9996,0.33  Three 0.0004  0.33
# 4:     8  Four:0.9986,0.22   Four 0.0014  0.22
# 5:     8  Five:0.9987,0.22   Five 0.0013  0.22
```

`tstrsplit` does `strsplit` and then `transpose` -- this takes the input string `x` and turns it into one column for each outcome of `split`ing each element of `x`.

In the second step, I assumed that `row` is a unique identifier of each row. This may be slow if there are a lot of `row`s -- you can try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44336733/3576984) for some other approaches to "unnesting" `V9` into different rows.

Then we `tstrsplit` again to get your desired value as its own column; note that `type.convert` will automatically convert columns that look like numbers, into numbers (instead of numbers-as-strings).

We could reverse this if you want the data back in the original string format, but it will be easier to work with your data in the current format.