# Any more concise `data.table` way to unnest a nested column in data.table?

Tags: r, nested, data.table, unnest

Assuming we have a `data.table` with a nested column `val`

```
dt <- data.table(
  grp = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4),
  val = list("a", c("b", "c"), c("d", "e", "f"), "g", c("h", "i"))
)
```

which shows as

```
> dt
   grp   val
1:   1     a
2:   2   b,c
3:   1 d,e,f
4:   3     g
5:   4   h,i
```

---

## Question

I would like to `unnest` the `val` column, where a possible option is using `tidyr::unnest`, i.e.,

```
> dt %>%
+   unnest(val)
# A tibble: 9 × 2
    grp val
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a
2     2 b
3     2 c
4     1 d
5     1 e
6     1 f
7     3 g
8     4 h
9     4 i
```

I am wondering if we can implement it by ***using the `data.table` only***.

**Watch out the order of values in the column `grp`, I would like to preserve the order like `1,2,1,3,4` rather than `1,1,2,3,4`.**

---

## My `data.table` Attempt

My attempt is as below

```
> dt[, id := .I][, lapply(.SD, unlist), id][, id := NULL][]
   grp val
1:   1   a
2:   2   b
3:   2   c
4:   1   d
5:   1   e
6:   1   f
7:   3   g
8:   4   h
9:   4   i
```

or

```
> dt[,.(grp = rep(grp,lengths(val)), val = unlist(val))]
   grp val
1:   1   a
2:   2   b
3:   2   c
4:   1   d
5:   1   e
6:   1   f
7:   3   g
8:   4   h
9:   4   i
```

but I guess there might be some more concise and elegant way to do this, e.g., without creating an auxiliary column `id` or using `rep` + `lengths`.

Any idea? Much appreciated!

Comment: Links to several SO posts here: [Create an efficient unnest function](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2146). Maybe some relevant?

Comment: E.g. [How to 'unlist' a column in a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336733/how-to-unlist-a-column-in-a-data-table), with suggestions similar to those here.

Comment: I really like the second solution (with rep and lengths).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One more option:

```
dt[, .(grp, val = unlist(val)), by = .I][, !"I"]
#      grp    val
#    <num> <char>
# 1:     1      a
# 2:     2      b
# 3:     2      c
# 4:     1      d
# 5:     1      e
# 6:     1      f
# 7:     3      g
# 8:     4      h
# 9:     4      i
```

PS. If you are using data.table `1.4.2` or older `by = .I` won't work. Instead you can use:

```
dt[, .(grp, val = unlist(val)), by = 1:nrow(dt)][, !"nrow"]
```

PS2. I think your `dt[,.(grp = rep(grp,lengths(val)), val = unlist(val))]` is neater.

Comment: For some reason, I cannot reproduce your output

Comment: The val column is correct, but the grp is all messed up: `   grp val
1:   1   a
2:   2   b
3:   1   c
4:   3   d
5:   4   e
6:   1   f
7:   2   g
8:   1   h
9:   3   i`

Comment: Would you mind adding every step? maybe it's just me

Comment: I have 1.14.2. Let's see if it works for other people; it is not my question after all; it's not a big deal if it does not work only on my session

Comment: I think found out the difference and added a note.

Comment: Nice solution of using `by = .I`!

Comment: same as @Maël, with data.table 1.14.2 I do not find the proper grp order, and have a warning message `Item 1 has 5 rows but longest item has 9; recycled with remainder`

Answer (score 7):

Another option without group `by` like this:

```r
library(data.table)
dt[rep(1:.N, lengths(val))][, val:=unlist(dt$val)][]
#>    grp val
#> 1:   1   a
#> 2:   2   b
#> 3:   2   c
#> 4:   1   d
#> 5:   1   e
#> 6:   1   f
#> 7:   3   g
#> 8:   4   h
#> 9:   4   i
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
dt <- dt[, .(grp, unlist(val)), by=.(rleid(grp))][, rleid := NULL]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this works:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, unlist), by = .(grp)]

   grp val
1:   1   a
2:   1   d
3:   1   e
4:   1   f
5:   2   b
6:   2   c
7:   3   g
8:   4   h
9:   4   i
```

Comment: It is a nice attempt, but the `grp` values should retain the same order as in the original `dt`, e.g., `1,2,1,3,4` rather than `1,1,2,3,4`.